# Invalid credentials error in Angularfire2 oauth login

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, angularfire, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to login to my Ionic 2 app using Facebook native and Angularfire2 (2.0.0-beta.2), but even though I am successfully getting an access token, no matter how I try to pass it in to angularfire's auth.login function it still throws an invalid credentials error.

Here is my config:

```
firebaseAuthConfig({
   provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
   method: AuthMethods.OAuthToken,
   remember: "default",
   scope: ["email"]
})
```

And here is my login function:

```
login() {
Facebook.login(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"])
  .then((success) => {
    console.log("Facebook success: " + JSON.stringify(success));
    this.af.auth.login(success.authResponse.accessToken, { provider: AuthProviders.Facebook })
      .then((success) => {
        console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(success));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Firebase failure: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Facebook failure: " + JSON.stringify(error));
  });
}
```

And here is the error I get in my console.log:

```
Facebook failure: {"code":"auth/argument-error","message":"signInWithCredential failed: First argument \"credential\" must be a valid credential."}
```

It's interesting that it's being caught at the Facebook level instead of the catch I have set up for the auth.login.  I have tried passing it in several different ways including as an object `{ token: success.authResponse.accessToken }` and I'm at a loss now.  Can anyone help me see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Also, I don't think this is related, but just in case it is I am also receiving a "operation has timed out error" that's not being caught but seems to be thrown by my this.af.auth.subscribe call. The app keeps running fine but perhaps that could be what's making the login fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform, ionicBootstrap} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
import {HomePage} from './pages/home/home';
import {Facebook} from 'ionic-native';

import {
  FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase,
  AngularFire, firebaseAuthConfig, AuthProviders,
  AuthMethods
} from 'angularfire2';


declare let firebase: any; // <== THERE IS AN ERROR IN THE .d.ts file

@Component({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
  providers: [
    FIREBASE_PROVIDERS,
    // Initialize Firebase app  
    defaultFirebase({}),
    firebaseAuthConfig({})
  ]
})

export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, public af: AngularFire) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();


      Facebook.login(['email'])
        .then((_response) => {
          console.log(_response)

          // IMPORTANT STEP !!
          let creds = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(_response.authResponse.accessToken)

          this.af.auth.login(creds,
            {
              provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
              method: AuthMethods.OAuthToken,
              remember: 'default',
              scope: ['email'],
            })
            .then((success) => {
              console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(success));
              alert(JSON.stringify(success))
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log("Firebase failure: " + JSON.stringify(error));
              alert(JSON.stringify(error))
            });

        })
        .catch((_error) => { console.log(_error) })
    });
  }
}

ionicBootstrap(MyApp);
```

https://github.com/aaronksaunders/AngularFire2-Ionic2-Facebook

Comment: Thank you! Well it changed the error so I assume this is headed in the right direction... Now I get a completely empty error after login. It just says "Facebook failure: {}".  Do you have any idea why that could be?

Comment: just try setting the scope to email... make sure you have configured the facebook app correctly.. I will post the complete app... but I suspect this is a configuration issue now.

Comment: It seems I spoke too soon.  There error was being thrown by it not recognizing "firebase" in the scope of the login function so I fixed that and now I still get the invalid credentials error. I'll keep working on it I do think you've helped me so I'll upvote your answer but it's late and I'll have to keep looking at it tomorrow.

Comment: i suggest you pull my project and add your keys and then go from there...

Comment: It took me a while but after creating a new project and following your method it finally worked.  Thanks so much @Aaron Saunders!